# install 2.13 gerrit its jira plugin on 2.6.1 gerrit server got pluginstallException error

Tags: plugins, gerrit

ubuntu version:4.6.3
gerrit version:2.6.1
its-jira plugin:2.13

1. already install its-base plugin successfully.
2. when using ssh to install its-jira plugin got following error, see attached picture, as canot copy content due to internal access limitation.

thanks for any help or hint, i did not find similar on Stackoverflow or google.

[see error msg in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6zy8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't install its-jira plugin **2.13** in Gerrit **2.6.1**.

Gerrit 2.6.1 is very old... consider to upgrade it to a new version.

Comment: thanks for your correction. we ever spespect version issue, but did not find clue in official gerrit or plugin webpage.   This is our company gerrit server, and no backup node yet, so would be hestitate to upgrade directly, in case blocking git/gerrit function.would appreciate if you have any good suggestion for such case. thanks again.